# Pandas applying with multi-indexed columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following working code that creates some simple maths functions and a DataFrame with multi-indexed columns. I would like to conditionally apply some functions over it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Simple maths functions  ---
def add(scalars): return sum(scalars)  #Adds every element in scalars
def sub(scalars): return (scalars[0] - sum(scalars[1:])) #First scalar value subtracted by the rest of the scalar list
def mul(scalars): return np.prod(scalars) #Multiplies every element in scalars
def divi(scalars): return (scalars[0] / np.prod(scalars[1:])) #First scalar value divided by the rest product of the scalar list
```

```
# Create df ---

operatorList = [add, sub, mul, divi]  # List of our maths functions
names = ['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'divi'] # List of the names of our maths functions
size = 4

tups = [('scalars', 'add', 'sc0'), ('scalars', 'add', 'sc1'), ('scalars', 'add', 'sc2'), ('scalars', 'sub', 'sc0'), ('scalars', 'sub', 'sc1'), ('scalars', 'mul', 'sc0'), ('scalars', 'mul', 'sc1'), ('scalars', 'mul', 'sc2'), ('scalars', 'divi', 'sc0'), ('scalars', 'divi', 'sc1'), ('operator', '', '')]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups))

df['operatorIndex'] = np.random.randint(0, len(names), size)
df['operator'] = df['operatorIndex'].apply(lambda x: str(names[x]))

groupSize = 2
df['ID']=np.divmod(np.arange(len(df)),groupSize)[0]+1
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

for name in names:
  df.loc[(df['operator'] == name), ('scalars', name, df.columns.levels[2])] = np.random.randint(0, 10)
```

```
> df

    scalars                                   operator  operatorIndex
    add         sub     mul         divi        
    sc0 sc1 sc2 sc0 sc1 sc0 sc1 sc2 sc0 sc1     
ID                                              
1   4   4   4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   add       0
1   NaN NaN NaN 7   7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   sub       1
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3   3   3   NaN NaN   mul       2
2   NaN NaN NaN 7   7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   sub       1
```

How can I create a new column called `Evaluation` which is the result of the correct mathematical function for each column? The column `operator` tells each row which function needs to be applied.

An example goal `df` would look like:

```
> df

    scalars                                   operator  operatorIndex  Evaluation
    add         sub     mul         divi        
    sc0 sc1 sc2 sc0 sc1 sc0 sc1 sc2 sc0 sc1     
ID                                              
1   4   5   6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   add       0              15
1   NaN NaN NaN 7   2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   sub       1              5
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   2   3   NaN NaN   mul       2              6
2   NaN NaN NaN 5   9   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   sub       1              -4
```

Comment: You're asking two questions in one - please ask two individual SO questions per question you have. :)

Answer (score 0):

This like this will work:

```py
df['Evaluation'] = df['operatorIndex'].apply(lambda operatorIndex: operatorList[operatorIndex](df['scalars'][names[operatorIndex]].min()))
```

Although it will only work if each operator has only one entry - if an op has multiple rows in the df, it will produce strange results.

You can fix that by storing a global counter that updates for each row, and using `iloc` to access the row of scalars by index:

```py
rowCounter = -1
def func(operatorIndex):
    global rowCounter
    rowCounter += 1
    return operatorList[operatorIndex](df['scalars'][names[operatorIndex]].iloc[rowCounter])

df['Evaluation'] = df['operatorIndex'].apply(func)
```

Comment: There will be many rows per operator so I can't use the first option. I'm also not very keen on using a global counter. I appreciate the effort though. I'm trying to adapt your first attempt into something though.
I have a hunch that ```apply()``` is involved but I'm having trouble getting both the ```operatorIndex``` and the scalars at the same time. Feels like I'd almost have to use an ```apply()``` inside another ```apply()```

Comment: I've adapted your answer. I think it's fully functional now. Let me know if it holds up to scrutiny. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to adapt the answer from @user17242583

```
df['Evaluation'] = df.apply(lambda row: operatorList[row['operatorIndex'].values[0]](row['scalars'][names[row['operatorIndex'].values[0]]].to_numpy()) , axis=1 )
```

I have no idea if this will be useful to anyone else, but here you go.